# Поиск пути и перемещение. ИИ

Tags: разработка-игр, искусственный-интеллект

Пишу простой ИИ.

Действия происходят на тайловой карте. С четырёх сторон карты появляются зомби и преследуют игрока с целью убить.

Я могу написать простой алгоритм A* для поиска кратчайшего пути, но трудности с тем, чтобы согласовать перемещение большого количества мобов сразу.

Размер карты не будет превышать 50х50 тайлов. Количество монстров не больше 200 на карте. На одном тайле может быть только один моб. Также есть объекты препятствующие перемещению, такие как стены, но они разрушаемы и при составлении пути имеют большую стоимость посещения. Мобы не могут проходить друг через друга, но есть возможность толкать соседа в направлении движения. Толчок сработает только в случае, если тайл куда толкают свободен.

Если кому-то нужен мой код, то вот ссылка на проект

https://github.com/StrikebyClaymore/2dAI

Важные для задачи скрипты называются *Pathfinder.gd* и *objects/Enemy.gd*

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что на одном тайле не может находиться больше 1 моба? И каждый ход моб должен сделать движение?

Comment: Правильно. На один тайл - один моб. Если функция движения вызывается, то моб будет совершать движение. Не понял, что вы имели ввиду под ходом.

Comment: Обычно игры с тайлами пошаговые, есть некие такты. Вопрос был в том, каждый ли такт ИИ должен поменять свое расположение.

Comment: Окей, теперь, поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Учитывая, что алгоритмы поиска пути реализованы для графов, то не совсем понятно, в чем конкретна проблема "согласовать" всех ИИ. Если клетка уже занята - значит эта вершина графа уже недоступна, а значит и никакой алгоритм поиска пути не будет учитывать эту клетку.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы не было никаких багов и лагов, но у меня не получается. Проблема заключается именно в этом. В результате нужно, чтобы зомби максимально эффективно добирались до игрока и атаковали его. Чтобы они занимали пространство наиболее эффективным способом. Уточню ещё некоторые детали в оп посте.

Comment: Уточните, что значит "лаги и баги". Верно реализованный A* не будет выдавать никаких проблем, если вопрос в производительности - считайте ИИ отдельным потоком, хотя 200 юнитов не должны так cpu просаживать. Что вы подразумеваете под "максимально эффективно"? Все адекватные поиски пути и так находят наиболее короткий путь до цели, в этом и есть их смысл.Если они должны учитывать какие-то не очевидные для алгоритма условия, относящиеся к самой игре - то вам вручную нужно менять вес ребер.

Comment: Если не учитывать клетку, которая занята, тогда будет ситуация в которой будет не занятая ячейка до которой нельзя дойти.
"Лаги и баги" значит, что программа виснет или сильно тормозит.  Непосредственно алгоритм А* работает нормально. Не понимаю, как изменение веса ребёр может помочь в учёте не очевидных условий. 
Если бы я мог более детально понять, что именно не так, то уже бы сам скорее всего всё сделал.

Comment: _Если бы я мог более детально понять, что именно не так, то уже бы сам скорее всего всё сделал._ - очевидно ошибка у тебя в алгоритме, но так как ты его не предоставляешь, точнее сказать невозможно.

Comment: @ИванСоблазн, то, что вы пытаетесь реализовать - странно и не совсем понятно, для чего это все. Если объекты могут друг друга двигать - то они априори будут друга выталкивать из оптимального расположения и бороться за самую оптимальную клетку, вам практически всегда придется перестраивать путь движения объекта. И это всё ещё не объяснение лагов, приведите конкретные цифры, сколько уходит времени на 1 кадр на просчитывание пути?

Comment: Я переписывал алгоритм заново уже 3 или 4 раза. Так что не вижу смысла в том, чтобы показывать его. Вопрос в том, как сделать из обычного А* алгоритма универсальный поиск пути для АИ зомби.

Comment: И да, недостижимость клетки в играх - вполне легальная ситуация, не понимаю, что вас так смущает.

Comment: Что значит "универсальный алгоритм"? Любой алгоритм поиска пути в графе универсальный. Я вам уже объяснил - то, что вы хотите менять местоположение других агентов во время поиска пути - бессмысленная с точки зрения движения ии логика. "Не вижу смысла код показывать, но он тормозит". Уж извините, мы тут не экстрасенсы, проьлемы кода без кода оценить проблематично.

Comment: Ребят, вы что так троллите?)
Если кому-то действительно интересен абсолютно бесполезный в решении моей задачи код, то вот ссылка на проект https://github.com/StrikebyClaymore/2dAI
Нужные файлы называются Pathfinder.gd и objects/Enemy.gd

Comment: @ИванСоблазн, все необходимое для пояснения должно быть непосредственно в вопросе. Для редактирования вопроса можно воспользоваться кнопкой [edit]